# Taylor series about (3+x)/(x+4)*exp(-x) expanded at x = - 4. How do i replicate what I see in wolfram?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm puzzled by wolfram alpha's results.   If i ask 'series $\frac{3+x}{4+x} (\exp  (-x))$ expanded at -4' It will return a series.   What method does it use to do this?   I'm familiar with Taylor series but doing this will lead to having zero in the denominator when -4 is plugged in. Anyone familiar with series expansions able to help?

Here is wolfram alpha's results:
$\frac{1}{20} e^4 (x+4)^4-\frac{5}{24} e^4 (x+4)^3+\frac{2}{3} e^4 (x+4)^2-\frac{3}{2} e^4 (x+4)-\frac{e^4}{x+4}+2 e^4$

(Where it is for some reason listed in reverse order when copied out of the program.)

[Here is a link to the wolfram alpha output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20%283%2bx%29/%284%2bx%29%2aExp%28-x%29%20at%20x%20=%20-4)

Even if i plug in values of n for the bottom series it doesnt seem to work or i just dont understand how to read this series.  Can someone please help walk me through this?

$\sum _{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n e^4 (4+x)^n (n!+(1+n)!)}{n! (1+n)!}+\sum _{1+n=0} -e^4 (4+x)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function has a pole at (x+4).

One way to get around this is to first multiply by $(x+4)$, take the taylor series as usual and then divide by $(x+4)$ term by term.

Another way is to isolate the root, by first multiplying by $(x+4)$ and setting $x=-4$. This gives $-e^4$

So subtract
$$
-\frac{e^4}{x+4}
$$
from the function. *This will get rid of the pole*. Proceed as usual and then add back
$$
-\frac{e^4}{x+4}
$$

By the way the $-e^4$ is called the residue of the pole.

I've done the work by hand and typed it up in LaTeX.  Here it is for anyone to see.
Ok so the first method takes me through the following steps:

$f^{0}(x) = (3+x)e^{-x},$  $f^{0}(-4) = -e^{4}$

$f^{1}(x) = -(2+x)e^{-x}+e^{-x},$  $f^{1}(-4) = 2e^{4}$

$f^{2}(x) = (1+x)e^{-x},$  $f^{1}(-4) = 3e^{4}$

so then to approximate with a quadratic $f(x) = -e^{4}+2e^{4}(x+4)-\frac{3e^{4}(x+4)^{2}}{2}$

now divide through with (x+4)

$f(x) = \frac{-e^{4}}{4+x}+\frac{2e^{4}(x+4)}{4+x}-\frac{3e^{4}(x+4)^{2}}{2(x+4)}$

you can see the simplification from here. Hope this helps.

Comment: great job and thank you.  I worked this out by hand and got it to work.  Since this site helps me so much i posted the steps so everyone can see.  Saved me a lot of pain.  Thank you.

It is interesting you can just remove poles when using taylor series then just stick them back in.  Poles have a superposition property it seems right?  You can add and subtract them as needed?

Comment: Yes for the last statement as long as the poles have finite multiplicity. If not you end up with a whole lot of mess!

Comment: @DanMiladinovich Thank you for sharing your work. Greatly appreciated

Comment: finite multiplicity means (4+x) has one root whereas (4+x)^2 has two roots?   I wont ask you to tell me what happens yet and hopefully i wont have to deal with it.  Enough headaches for today. I'll save that question for if i run into it later.

Comment: Yes. Try it with $(4+x)^2$ in the denominator. Wolfram gives $-e^4/(x+4)^2+(2 e^4)/(x+4)-(3 e^4)/2+2/3 e^4 (x+4)-5/24 e^4 (x+4)^2+1/20 e^4 (x+4)^3+O((x+4)^4)$

Comment: Not much a mess to me. Looks like the term without the pole just shifts to the right once. Or without the convoluted mind of mine i meant to say just divide by one more (4+x).

Comment: You got it...  now see what happens if the order of the pole is infinite! Then you end up with a mess on your hand and this trick won't work. Technically where the trick does not work is called an *essential singularity*. You will meet these weird (they are weird in my opinion!) in a complex analysis course. But what I consider weird, others may consider *beautiful* so take it with a large pinch of salt.